# ¿Cómo poner valores en una fila, si se cumple una condición en pandas?

Tags: pandas

¿Cómo podría hacer para con pandas agregar una columna en la que diga "in time" si el valor de una columna es menor a 30 y "out of time" si el valor de la columna es mayor a 30?

Estoy tratando de formularla de la siguiente manera:

```
desercion_laboral ['on time/ out of time'] = desercion_laboral.get_loc[desercion_laboral['edad_ultima_prom'] <= 30, 'on time/ out of time'] == 'on time'
```

Pero no me sale, ¿alguien me podría orientar?

Comment: Para dar una respuesta más exacta, podrías colocar tu DataFrame?

Comment: Para cualquiera que esté en la cola de revisiones. Me equivoqué y le di dejar abierta. Esta pregunta debe ser cerrada (a mi criterio)